# Signs as part of a number coordinate

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, soft-question

Suppose we have a 1-dimensional space: a number line. We can name each element of it using its module and a "sign"(+/-).

Is there a system which have something like additional signs that are used to name numbers? In other words: Is there any property like *signness* which unite "+" and "-", and **can we create new object with such property**?

I am not talking of signs of operation like (multiplication $\times$) (division $\div$) etc. that are working on the same number line. They can not be used to name a number like "$\times4$"... *as far as I get it*

I came up with a system of n rays that are sent from one point, so we can name each ray with some symbol and use it to name numbers on it.
Example:

1. we have 3 rays and 3 operations that are "pulling" a result to the corresponding $\infty$ : addition, upperSubtraction and lowerSubtraction.

```
upperMinus infinity
\
 \
  \________ plus infinity
  /
 /
/
lowerMinus infinity
```

2. we have **upperMinus 4**
3. we do **plus 8** and get **plus 4**
4. we **lowerMinus 8** and get **lowerMinus 4**
5. we **upperMinus 8** and get **upperMinus 4** again

Maybe my presupposition about ability to call number ***n**(multiply n) is wrong. We can create a number line with 1/identity as origin and * will be treated like plus sign or *sign to the right of identity* and / will be a minus sign or *left sign*. **But there are still only two off them in one system!**

I think that i might be confused by having concepts like:

- number "$-4$" per se and not an operation "-" with magnitude 4
- not thinking of number line having an intrinsic operation hence the "sign" used as a part of coordinate.
  Example:
  we have 2 number lines
  first is based on addition and it has intrinsic addition/negative addition(subtruction) and we can use sign/negate sign of intrinsic operation as part of coordinate (+ we can "create" a multiplication in this basis)

```
 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
-3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3
```

second is using multiplication so we have $\div$ and $\times$ as intrinsic signs

```
 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
/4 /3 /2  1 *2 *3 *4
```

so probably one can even call it not a number line but an ~operation line.
I think that in lambda calculus the number(Church numeral) itself is an operation with some magnitude

Comment: In math we can do what ever we like.  I don't see enough in here to see why the positive/negative doesn't apply or why this isn't so abstract to apply to anything.  I mean why can't I use $*$ refer to make a set be power set or whatever....."
    we have upperMinus 4
    we do plus 8 and get plus 4
    we lowerMinus 8 and get lowerMinus 4
    we upperMinus 8 and get upperMinus 4 again
"  Well, I for one, can not comprehend what you mean by any of this.

Comment: @fleablood
in "normal" number line you only have two signs (eg "+ -"  /  "* /" )
-4 +4
i want to think of a system in which number line would have more signs like
-4 _4 +4
the question implicitly asks if there are any researched objects that remind of this

Comment: I still maintain this is too abstract to not apply to anything we want.

Comment: what should we "want"? I want to explore such a concept and if anyone studied it. I guess thats enough to be interested for me. I am sorry if it made you annoyed.

Comment: "what should we "want"" That's for *you* to describe.

Comment: How did you go from "lowerMinus $4$" and "upperMinus $8$" to get "upperMinus $4$"? What is the idea behind that? You should make clear how your system works with more general rules, instead of only $4$ and $8$ with different signs.

Comment: i can try to repeat: I want to explore a concept of 1-dimensional number system with multiple signs and if somebody studied it.

Comment: @jjagmath i told that each operation pulls to corresponding infinity.
lets agree that _:lowerminus; -:upperminus; +: plus
so we have
_1-1 = 0 | _1+1 = 0 |
-1_1 = 0 | -1+1 = 0 |
1-1 = 0   | 1_1 = 0 |

you can also say that we subtract modules and write the sign of the greater number

Comment: Oh, I get it now.

Comment: and ?disclaimer? i dont think it is only system with such property(at least i hope so). Its purpose was only to illustrate the concept

Answer (score 3):

The system you create is kind of neat, but your operations lack some of the basic properties we generally like to see in mathematical systems (particularly for operations called "$+$"):

1. No associativity, ie $(x + y) + z \neq x + (y + z)$ in your system. For example:

- $(2 + upperMinus 4) + lowerMinus 4 = lowerMinus 2$, but
- $2 + (upperMinus4 + lowerMinus4) = 0$.

2. No unique inverses. Since $2$ has two different things it can be added to that make $0$, this means that you can't have a concept of the negative of a number, which means you can't have a well-defined subtraction operation.

Without these, you're going to struggle to find any useful applications for this system, as you'll be unable to do most algebraic manipulations or use basic algebraic concepts like "the sum of three numbers".

A more standard approach to extending the real number line is to extend it to the [complex number plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane).

Comment: Great answer @MartianInvader - the Complex number system was what immediately came to mind when I was thinking of this. Maybe vectors or quaternions (depending on how liberally you want to interpret the meaning of "sign"?

Comment: the complex plane is kind of an answer, but it is homological to 2 dimensional number(so they just have 2 numbers with respective + -). i want my system to be ~1 dimensional

Comment: i tried to make some aplicable use case for this system in multi agent debt simulation... but it turned out strange

Comment: i guess that second expression will be
2+(-4+_4) = 2, because -4 and _4 annihilate each other.

Comment: i came up with a example.... its rgb colors! If you set brightness as a constant, origin as white color, you can "pull" output color towards one of red/green/blue.

Comment: "RGB color" usually mean expressing a variety of colors by breaking them down into their red, green, and blue components. Your system would ONLY support purely red, purely green, or purely blue colors, since there's no notion of "mixed" values that have components from more than one branch of your number tree.

Answer (score 0):

Let me take this back to a really fundamental level for a moment.

If we want to start a Group we need a set and an operation. What the set and operation are can be decided later, but for argument's sake I will use $S={0,1,2,3,4,5...}$

In order to successfully define an operation, the set $S$ must first be **closed** under this operation.

So I can define $a\circ b$ however I like so long as $a\circ b$ is a member of $S$ whenever $a$ and $b$ are members of $S$.

As was mentioned earlier, associativity is also a requirement, so we need $a\circ(b\circ c)=(a\circ b)\circ c$ for all $a,b,c$ in $S$.

Commutativity would be a bonus, and unless we want $S$ to be a semi-group we also require every element to have a unique inverse within $S$.

Not to mention a single identity element.

Now... what *operations* that we already know follow these requirements?

RBG colors can be considered a 3D number system or a six-digit code. If that is the case, I would argue that Complex numbers are similarly one-dimensional if you are willing to adjust your definition of *dimension*.